# socket listen and accept in C programme language

Tags: c, sockets

Here my socket.c as server simply listen on a port: 
the succinct code like below, I just want the code listening but not exit the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int so = socket(0,1,0);

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    bzero(&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

    listen(so,5);

    accept(so,NULL,NULL);


    return 0;

}
```

absolutely some hard code in here.
but when I gcc a.c compile it and run it. it will exit rather than listening.

So what's wrong with my code ????????????

Comment: Have you considered storing the result of any of these system calls? And checking them for errors? And printing the errors?

Comment: And are you missing `bind`. please read the manual pages for each of those system calls and consider the return values

Comment: `socket(0,1,0);` --> `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/?utm_source=feedburner

Comment: @EJP  I don't think which you say will affect my result, I just want listening not exit!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Ed Heal  I just want listen not receive some data!!!!!

Comment: well you need to bind to a port. Also you need to write code that takes errors into account

Comment: @Ed Heal   Yes, you are right, it's my so-so, but if I add
bind(so,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
above line, it dosen't listening~~~~~

Comment: @suoyong If you think correct error checking and reporting isn't necessary, or would make no difference to this question, you are deluding yourself. You have encountered an error, which needs to be detected and logged. You can't write code like this, **ever,** and you can't post it here, miraculously expecting a solution, without having made the slightest attempt yourself to identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating a stream socket over `AF_INET`that's why its not listening to the socket.

The code for `AF_INET` is `2` and not `0`.

change the code as

```
int so = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

or

```
 int so = socket(2, 1, 0);
```

it will work

You also need to bind the port number on which the server will listen. Binding is not must for `client` port but is a must for `Server` port number

```
bind(so, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

Comment: Please mention that binding to a port is required

Comment: Thanks for the catch.. Added it with explanation

Comment: @Daksh Gupta   Yes,you are right. but on Window system, if I set AF_UNSPEC which is 0 insteadof AF_INET, the windows socket will work.

Comment: @Suoyong  Windows by default treat UnSpecified as INET, not the case with all the systems